# Guessing/determining the column data types for a CSV?

Tags: database, csv, schema, column-types

I have the CSV for some time (suppose it's an RFC-compliant CSV with no syntax errors), with a header line containing columnn names. Howevwer, I don't have the intended data type of each column.

What would be a quick-and-not-so-dirty way to guess those column types?

Notes:

- Motivation: I want to load the CSV into a DB table, but I have to create the table first.
- I'm interested in a shell-script'y solution, but other alternatives might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL loader for loading csv file in a accurate way. If you want to know how to create SQL loader